# Github hook for milestone

Tags: github, project-management, webhooks, milestone

I want to integrate github with a external service.
In particular I want certain actions to happen when an issue closes or a milestone is completed. I can see how to do the above for issues by adding a webhook against the issue event updates http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/.
However, I don't see any events around milestones.

Why is that? Is it an ommission? I have seen some integrations of github milestones with the google calendar - I am assuming that this requires webhooks (I wouldn't expect them to use polling against the milestone api).

One alternative I have thought if there is no such event, is to listen for issue events and every time an issue closes, check whether this issue is associated with a milestone, and if it is check whether all other issues associated with that milestone are already closed and then create my own "milestone completed" event. ( I don't need milestone create events).

Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: It seems that milestones are not "first class" object in github, the way issues for example are. For example there seems to be no way for someone to point to a particular milestone - and see its detail.
It is more of a grouping construct. This may explain why there will not exist an hook for its update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, there are no milestone events at this time. Your idea using issue events and checking the [milestone closed issues count](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/milestones/#get-a-single-milestone) is probably the way I'd do it too. Remember to use conditional GETs when fetching the milestone info in order to [reduce your API quota consumption](http://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests).

Answer (score 0):

There are now webhook events for milestones - introduced by Github in October 2016. See:

https://developer.github.com/changes/2016-10-27-new-label-and-milestone-webhooks/